# Find which one of the WHERE clauses succeeded

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query where I use an OR after the WHERE like this.

```
SELECT * FROM blah WHERE id='$id' OR name='$name'
```

The query is successful but I need to know at made the query successful, the id or the name. Is there a method that can do this?

Comment: Just a thought.  You could look at the results.  Order by name or id, if it makes it easier.

Comment: What if they both match? Because of the way the `WHERE` condition is ordered `id` will always take precedent over `name` - does it matter? If it doesn't matter, then merely the fact that you've got a record tells you that something matched and then @durbnpoisn is bang on - just look at the results.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I checked the results against what I had used for the query in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could check the result (ie. `if( $result['id'] == $id)`)

Or do this in the MySQL:

```
SELECT *, `id` = :id as `idmatched`, `name` = :name as `namematched`
FROM `blah` WHERE `id` = :id OR `name` = :name
```

Note: use named parameters and stuff. That's what PDO is good at ^_^

Answer (score 1):

If you need it in the query result, you could do something like:

```
SELECT blah.*,
       (CASE WHEN id='$id' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) first_condition,
       (CASE WHEN name='$name' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) second_condition,
FROM blah
WHERE id='$id' OR name='$name'
```

Comment: I +1'd you, but maybe you're getting downvotes because you're not fixing the injection problem (see the parameter use in my code), and possibly because you're doing the MySQL equivalent to `if( x == true) return true; else return false;`