# Find which where clause is the most troublesome

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

**Problem background**

I am trying to pin down to what condition(s) are causing no records / rows the most, so to allow me to find the root cause of what data in the database might need scrubbing.

So for example from the following query I would like to know whether it was the first condition which fails most of the time or second condition is the most offending one and so on.

```
SELECT TOP 1
FROM table 
WHERE column1 = @param1  -- (cndtn 1)This condition works without anding with other conditions
  AND column2 = @param2
  AND column3 = @param3  -- (cndtn 3) This with 1 works 10% of the time
  AND column4 = @param4
```

One of the ideas I thought was to break the procedure to use one condition at a time.

```
DECLARE @retVal int

SELECT @retVal = COUNT(*) 
FROM table
WHERE column1 = @param1

IF (@retVal > 0)
   --Do Something like above but by using @param2, @param3 and so on
```

**Issues**

1. If first check itself fails I wouldn't have a way forward to investigate into other combinations.
2. This doesn't seem very efficient either as this stored procedure is called hundreds of times.

**Other SO Post** I also find this great post ([Find which one of the WHERE clauses succeeded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23113024/2719527)) but this isn't very helping when no records are returned.

Comment: If this is just for debugging, what about detecting when the @@ROWCOUNT = 0 and storing the parameters in a separate debugging table? Then you could use the data in that table later on in your own query script, without having to worry about it's impact on a frequently invoked procedure.

Comment: Do you mean, storing parameters value?, If yes I am able to do it from C# side, but what I do not know, is which condition failed when the proc was called upon.

Comment: And By Failed I mean, the condition which resulted in Zero Records returned.

Comment: If you know the parameter values, you can write a separate script or procedure to tell you which conditions return a count of 0, similar to the post linked above. Since it'll consist of all `select count(*)'s .... where someCondition = paramX`, it won't be terribly efficient sql-wise, but since it's just occaisional troubleshooting it won't interfere with the main proc, that seems okay

Comment: Here's an example that returns a count(*) of matching rows for each parameter. If the count = 0, you know that condition "failed". Again, it's not designed for efficiency, but should return the info you need https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c05b8360695d191695684c7393f411c5

Comment: Thank you, let me review it in the evening.

Comment: Sounds good. Here's another version to try later. It returns `1` when the condition "fails", and `null` if it succeeds.  It's still not optimized for efficiency, but the `not exists...` is probably slightly faster than a full `count(*)`. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f72445e1d39697cce173d0312e1fe31d

Comment: @SOS Time did not allow me to look into this earlier, but I like what you have done sir. Do you mind putting this as an answer for folks wondering similar questions and coming to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is just for debugging, what about detecting when the `@@ROWCOUNT = 0` and storing those parameters in a separate debugging table?

```
SELECT  TOP 1 *
FROM    SomeTable
WHERE   column1 = @param1 
AND     column2 = @param2
AND     column3 = @param3 
AND     column4 = @param4
-- order by ....
;    

-- one or more parameters "failed"
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO SomeTable_Debug( createdDate, column1, column2, column3, column4, column5)
     VALUES (getDate(), @param1, @param2, @param3, @param4, @param5)
END
```

You can then use the debugging table later on, in a separate query script, without having to worry about it's impact on a frequently invoked procedure. For example, this query returns `1` when a condition "fails", otherwise it returns `null`. It's not optimized for efficiency, but should be fine for occasional debugging use:

```
SELECT *
       , (SELECT 1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM SomeTable st WHERE st.column1 = d.column1)) AS Matches_Column1
       , (SELECT 1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM SomeTable st WHERE st.column2 = d.column2)) AS Matches_Column2
       , (SELECT 1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM SomeTable st WHERE st.column3 = d.column3)) AS Matches_Column3
       , (SELECT 1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM SomeTable st WHERE st.column4 = d.column4)) AS Matches_Column4
       , (SELECT 1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM SomeTable st WHERE st.column5 = d.column5)) AS Matches_Column5
FROM   SomeTable_Debug d
```

**Sample Results:**

| id | createdDate | column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | column5 | Matches_Column1 | Matches_Column2 | Matches_Column3 | Matches_Column4 | Matches_Column5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-04-18 16:51:11.487 | 1 | 22 | 3 | 4 | 5 | *null* | 1 | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 2 | 2022-04-18 16:51:11.500 | 1 | 22 | 3 | 4 | 56 | *null* | 1 | *null* | *null* | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8f74a454d766039f0ca06114f0bde1a4)*